# Improve sql query performance in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

My existing query looks like:

```
SELECT p.subcode as proc_subcode,
       r.subcode as rv_subcode,
       r.rlv,
       f.cfid,
       f.geozip,
       p.proc,
       p.sh_descr,
       f.begproc,
       f.endproc,
       p.descr,
       r.modi,
       f.per25
  FROM user.code p, user.relative r, user.frequency f
 WHERE f.ID = 'XOF'
   AND f.GEOZIP = '200'
   AND f.REL_DATE = '10-SEP-13'
   AND p.proc IN ('A0021', 'A0080', 'A0090', 'A0100', 'A0110', 'A0120',
        'A0130', 'A0140', 'A0160', 'A0170', 'A0180', 'A0190',
        'A0200', 'A0210', 'A0225')
   AND r.ID = f.ID
   AND f.REL_DATE = r.REL_DATE
   AND f.ID = p.ID
   AND f.REL_DATE = p.REL_DATE
   AND p.proc = r.proc
   AND p.proc between f.begproc AND f.endproc
   AND (('A0021' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0021' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0021' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0080' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0080' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0080' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0090' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0090' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0090' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0100' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0100' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0100' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0110' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0110' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0110' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0120' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0120' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0120' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0130' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0130' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0130' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0140' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0140' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0140' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0160' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0160' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0160' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0170' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0170' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0170' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0180' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0180' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0180' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0190' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0190' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0190' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0200' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0200' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0200' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0210' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0210' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0210' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0225' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0225' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0225' AND f.CFID = '00'))
 ORDER BY p.proc, r.modi, f.REL_DATE asc
```

The above query works well, however, I'm planning to add 100s of p.proc in range, for ex. it would be like A0021-A1000. So, I want to improve the sql query performance.

Can anybody help?

Edit 1:

I suppose possible solution would be to remove IN clause for p.proc and make use of between.  I'm not sure of the last AND condition though.

Edit 2:

Explanation of the query

I'm basically getting all the medical cost for a specific region using geozip and passing the code, for ex. A0021 means surgery code & 200 means New York & 10-september-2013 is the release date and getting results for the product called XOF.

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because the question is explicitly about Oracle.

Comment: Could you show  us data and explain meaning of your query?

Comment: "toms rule #1: never compare strings to dates and dates to strings.  Always compare 
strings to string and dates to dates!"

Comment: @MikkaRin - just edited the question to explain what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
 WHERE f.ID = 'XOF'
   AND f.GEOZIP = '200'
   AND f.REL_DATE = '10-SEP-13'
   AND p.proc IN ('A0021', 'A0080', 'A0090', 'A0100', 'A0110', 'A0120',
        'A0130', 'A0140', 'A0160', 'A0170', 'A0180', 'A0190',
        'A0200', 'A0210', 'A0225')
   AND r.ID = f.ID
   AND f.REL_DATE = r.REL_DATE
   AND f.ID = p.ID
   AND f.REL_DATE = p.REL_DATE
   AND p.proc = r.proc
   AND p.proc between f.begproc AND f.endproc
   AND (('A0021' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0021' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0021' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0080' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0080' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0080' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
       ('A0090' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0090' AND
       r.PROC = 'A0090' AND f.CFID = '00') OR....
```

in your query p.proc=r.proc. So you no need to write it each time in these statements:

```
 ('A0090' BETWEEN f.BEGPROC AND f.ENDPROC AND p.PROC = 'A0090' AND
   r.PROC = 'A0090' AND f.CFID = '00') OR
```

in all these statements also f.CFID='00'. You no need to write it in each statement. Currently I think that all what you need is :

```
WHERE f.ID = 'XOF'
       AND f.GEOZIP = '200'
       AND f.REL_DATE = '10-SEP-13'
       AND p.proc IN ('A0021', 'A0080', 'A0090', 'A0100', 'A0110', 'A0120',
            'A0130', 'A0140', 'A0160', 'A0170', 'A0180', 'A0190',
            'A0200', 'A0210', 'A0225')
       AND r.ID = f.ID
       AND f.REL_DATE = r.REL_DATE
       AND f.ID = p.ID
       AND f.REL_DATE = p.REL_DATE
       AND p.proc = r.proc
       AND p.proc between f.begproc AND f.endproc
       AND f.CFID='00'
```

these 4 statements

```
           AND p.proc IN ('A0021', 'A0080', 'A0090', 'A0100', 'A0110', 'A0120',
                'A0130', 'A0140', 'A0160', 'A0170', 'A0180', 'A0190',
                'A0200', 'A0210', 'A0225')
           AND p.proc = r.proc
           AND p.proc between f.begproc AND f.endproc
           AND f.CFID='00'
```

make the same that all these BETWEEEN statements.

please check this query on your data

Comment: Thanks MikkaRin. Is there a way to avoid p.proc IN clause. My user may input 1000 code in range, for ex. A0021-A1000.

Comment: Also, f.CFID='00' is not always constant, depending on the query, it may become f.CFID = '01' for different code

Comment: I think there is no way to avoid IN clause, since you store `proc` in `string`. For CFID you may do where clause like this: `AND ((p.proc IN (...) AND f.CFID='00') OR (p.proc IN (...) AND f.CFID='01')) AND ....`